# Detect if PDO->execute returns a row/record?

Tags: php, pdo, execute

code example;

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT u.username, u.display_name FROM users u WHERE u.id = :userId');
$stmt->bindValue(':userId', 10);
$stmt->execute();
```

Using prepare -> execute. If your sure the query will return max 1 row; is there a simple way to see if query did return a row? I see everyone validating on 'rowCount', but isn't there a cleaner way?

this article: http://www.christiansouth.com/php/pdo-getting-started-part-2-pdostatement/
states;

> TRUE if the query was successful FALSE if it wasn’t. The stumble here
>   is it will ONLY return FALSE if the SQL has an error. So if the SQL is
>   valid but return no rowset you will still get a TRUE return value.

Is this statement correct? Because php.net only talks about:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

So, rapping up the questions again:

- Is it true you can't validate if a row was returned using $stmt (in above example) as
  a boolean?
- Is there any solution to this that looks cleaner then 'rowCount' rapped in an if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Use* the result-set (i.e. [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)): was there a row or not?

A result-set with 0 records is still perfectly valid in terms of "did it work" and is why TRUE is returned on *every* valid query `execute`'ed. In this case FALSE should be treated only as an *exception condition*.

On the other hand, the result from (the first) `fetch` - combined with the knowledge that the query will only return 0..1 rows - can be used to determine if there was a single row fetched. Since this is the "standard" way to access the data for such a query, there is no need to perform an additional check.

Comment: So I can use $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); if ($result) //found a row; ?

Comment: fetching from an empty result set is going to return an error.  I still don't see why you would want to do this, when you already have the rowCount available to you in the $stmt object from rowCount()

Comment: @gview What is the *result* of `fetch` on an empty result set? (Hint: it's `FALSE`.) This is a *separate* issue from the result of `execute` on an empty result set (which is `TRUE` if a valid query)! This particular issue isn't about finding out how many results were returned in a general sense - the result-set for this *particular query/usage* is designed to return 0..1 records (it's a non-join query with single Key selection). Now, perhaps it could be argued that the code should "check that *at most* one record is returned", but .. I'll just leave that there.

Comment: @pst I agree with you, and I don't see a problem with your answer, given the context of the question.   It's just not necessary to even do a fetch when you already know there is no result, since the client already has that information available from rowCount().  I could also argue that rowCount() is superior in that it has additional information that could be valuable -- like the fact that the result which expected only 0..1, actually has > 1.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are working with mysql, rowCount will provide you the number in the result set without having to do another query.  Other databases may not support rowCount accurately, so you'd have to do a seperate select count(*) ... query first.

As for whether you only get true or false on an execute, that is absolutely going to be true, even for queries that return no rows.  This is because in relational theory, an empty result set is completely valid, and a select with no rows is not an error.

Answer (score -3):

Use exec();

From the PHP manual:

> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec() returns 0.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Comment: I feel it answers this question: "Is there any solution to this that looks cleaner then 'rowCount' rapped in an if?"

Comment: You have a wrong feeling. Moreover, you cannot substitute execute() with exec(). Frankly, you need a little more experience to answer already answered questions.

Comment: The question was about SELECT statement. while exec doesn't return anything for it

Comment: Ahhh. Looks like I should have read the PHP manual page that I linked and the question more carefully.  My mistakes.  Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Looking into question even deeper, grasping the *whole matter*  instead of just picking one sentence out of context, one can tell that the OP don't need no number of rows at all. As it was stated in the accepted answer, the returned data is more than enough itself.